# How to disable connection pooling in Webclient in new Springboot 2.1.4.Release?

Tags: spring-boot, reactor-netty

I am using springboot webclient to call rest api from remote server. First request works fine. If I made subsequent request after sometime, the server throws 500 server error. The error I got is " onError(java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host)".

I want to test the behavior with disabling connection  pool since I believe it uses the previous connection. Can you help me how to disable the connection pool when creating webclient?

```
TcpClient tcpClient = TcpClient.create()
        .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 30000)
        .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, false)
        .doOnConnected(connection ->
                connection.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(30))
                        .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(30))
        );

ReactorClientHttpConnector httpConnector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.from(tcpClient));

final WebClient webClient = WebClient
        .builder()
        .clientConnector(httpConnector)
        .baseUrl("http://customer.service.api.internal.cloud.qa.intranet.pagseguro.uol")
        .exchangeStrategies(strategies)
        .build()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can disable the connection pooling using the code below

```
TcpClient tcpClient = TcpClient.newConnection()
```

Use `wiretap(true)` to inspect the traffic between the server and the client.

You can also enable the logging for Reactor Netty and trace whether the connection is reused (in the connection pool scenario)

```
logging.level.reactor.netty=debug
```

If the connection is reused you will see

```
2019-04-11 18:52:10.049 DEBUG 98105 --- [ctor-http-nio-5] r.n.resources.PooledConnectionProvider   : [id: 0x897584fa, L:/<IP>:<PORT> - R:/<IP>:<PORT>] Channel acquired, now 1 active connections and 0 inactive connections
```

Also using the channel id `id: 0x897584fa` you can track what's happening with the channel.

Comment: Can you look into this question and help me out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55621800/springboot-webclient-throws-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-r